# PHP fwrite() cannot write to subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

My website is on `/var/www/html/hs/`, where I have my **update.php**. It is supposed to write to `/var/www/html/hs/json/myFile.json`, but it just doesn't. When I try writing to the same directory of **update.php**, no problems seem to occur.

**update.php** file-writing code part thing:

```
$fileJSON = fopen("json/$fileName.json", "w");
fwrite($fileJSON, $JSONE);
fclose($fileJSON);
```

I (believe) have already given myself the necessary permissions through `sudo chown -R myName /var/www/`.

> System: Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2
>   23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64
>
> PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
>
> Apache Version Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Does the `json` directory exist? If not, you need to create it.

Comment: Check your error_log !

Comment: The directory did exist, and I /var/log/apache2/error.log didn't anything either. Neverthless, the chmod actually worked for me, apparently :D Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have the necessary permissions. Check what your error_log has to say about this!

You should not `chown` to your own username, but the use username that is running Apache. (Use `ps -aux | grep httpd` to see which user it is. Once chowned, the directory might become inaccessible for you if you don't also have root.

Another thing you can do is `chmod` *the directory that you want to write to* to `777`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `json/` directory doesn't exist, you'll need to create it:

```
if (!is_dir('json'))
    mkdir('json');
```